# Is it possible to use album art as an icon for a folder in Nautilus Elementary?

Tags: 11.04, icons, music, nautilus-elementary, directory

I run Ubuntu 11.04 with Nautilus Elementary. Is it possible in Nautilus to use album art as an icon (miniature) of a folder where the album is stored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Yes. Add the [**Cover Thumbnailer**](http://software.flogisoft.com/cover-thumbnailer/en/) PPA, and install cover thumbnailer from the Software Center. It will automatically set your covers as the folder icon.*

### Graphical method:

To add the PPA, open your software sources and add:

```
ppa:flozz/flozz
```

Then install [cover-thumbnailer](http://packages.ubuntu.com/cover-thumbnailer) [image: Install cover-thumbnailer] from the Software Center.

### **Or, run the following in a terminal:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:flozz/flozz
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cover-thumbnailer
```

Comment: Installed 0.8.2 version yesterday, works like a charm :-)

Comment: @Wojciech: awesome :D!